# Binding Events to Commands without Blend SDK or third party. (WPF / MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

Is there a way to bind Events to command **without** `System.Windows.Interactivity` or any other third party library?

So far I have tried the following:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
      <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick"
      Handler="{Binding DoubleClickCommand}" />
</Style>
```

And

```
<DataGrid.InputBindings>
      <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding DoubleClickCommand}"/>
</DataGrid.InputBindings>
```

And

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Model.SpectrumCollections}"
          ColumnWidth="*"
          AutoGenerateColumns="false"
          IsReadOnly="True" 
          BorderThickness="0"
          HeadersVisibility="Column" MouseDoubleClick="{Binding DoubleClickCommand}">
```

But nothings seems to work, any help will be much appreciated.

Edit 1:
This is my implementation of the RelayCommand I use, maybe the problem is there..

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Func<bool> _canExecute;

    private readonly Action _execute;

    public RelayCommand(Action inExecute, Func<bool> inCanExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = inExecute ?? throw new Helper.Exceptions.DelegateCommandException(
                       Exceptions.InExecuteIsNullException);
        _canExecute = inCanExecute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object inObject) => _canExecute?.Invoke() ?? true;

    public void Execute(object inObject) => _execute?.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: Why you don't want to use, already made package, that does exactly what you are asking for?

Comment: Because one of the requirements for the project is to not use third party packages, sadly.
And I believe that it should not be that hard to implement.

Comment: `System.Windows.Interactivity` is a part of Blend SDK. Which is a designer software for WPF apps. I wouldn't class it as a third party package as it is used specifically for Blend. Now I got this to work however you would have to specify the `DataTemplate` for each `Cell`. And your second attempt will work only when user double clicks on actual `DataGrid` **NOT** `Cell`, there is a difference. Double click on a Cell triggers edit mode.

Comment: Everything work fine with MouseBinding Command="{Binding DoubleClickCommand}" Gesture="LeftDoubleClick"

Comment: I see your point @XAMlMAX, and I completly understand the meaning of reinventing the wheel, but I'm not who did the requirements.

Comment: @AndrewShkolik it doesn't enter in the Command when I double click on a cell, but I guess XAMIMAX point it out already. I have to click on a free space in  the Grid.

Comment: Actually this would not be an additional dependency, when you get the SDK it installs into `GAC` so your app would not contain any additional components, but the target machine would have to have the dll in the `GAC`.

Comment: "_But the target machine would have to have the dll in the GAC_" is exactly what I'm trying to avoid =). Take a look on the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do the following because `MouseDoubleClick` is en event and not a dependency property:

```
MouseDoubleClick="{Binding DoubleClickCommand}">
```

You can bind to the `Command` property of a `MouseBinding` though:

```
<DataGrid.InputBindings>
    <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding DoubleClickCommand}"/>
</DataGrid.InputBindings>
```

If you want to invoke the command when you double-click on a cell, you should add the `MouseBinding` to the `DataGridCell`:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}">
                                <ContentPresenter.InputBindings>
                                    <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick"
                                                  Command="{Binding DataContext.DoubleClickCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
                                </ContentPresenter.InputBindings>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <DataGrid.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding DoubleClickCommand}"/>
    </DataGrid.InputBindings>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```